# Как реализовать сохранение SurfaceView в файл?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, изображения, android-canvas

Я рисую прямоугольники с использованием Canvas, динамически перемещаю и изменяю SurfaceView, я использую кнопку для сохранения("Save")

```
class DrawThread extends Thread { // класс потка холдэра

private boolean running = false; //переменная дающая спусковой крючок к запуску
private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
private Drawable drawing;

public DrawThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
    this.surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
}


public void setRunning(boolean running) {
    this.running = running;
}

public void run() {

    drawing = new Drawing(bitmap);
    while (running) {
        canvas = null; // пока присваеваем ноль
        try {

            canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null); //получаем конву
            if (canvas == null) continue; // если канвы нет то начинаем цикл заново
            // drawing.draw(canvas);

            canvas.drawColor(Color.GRAY);


           } finally {
            if (canvas != null) {
                surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas); //выводит на экран наше художество
            }
        }


    }
}



public void onSaveImage(View view) {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(CanvasInProject.this,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
            101);


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Должна быть процедура для рисования ваших объектов прямоугольников на Canvas. После нажатия кнопки Save запускается другая активность (динамика приостанавливается), здесь если надо можно ввести имя файла и т.п. Создаете Bitmap нужных размеров, создаете к нему Canvas и передаете в основную процедуру для рисования, после чего [сохраняете](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649154/save-bitmap-to-location) Bitmap в файл.

Comment: А как передать из Canvas к Bitmap?

Comment: canvas.setBitmap( bitmap ); На всякий случай уточню, что процедура рисования для SurfaceView и для Save одна, где вы передаете как аргумент канву и возможно объекты для рисования.

Comment: Я реализовал сохранение по вашей рекомендации она помогла, но при запуске SurfaceView он белый(пустой в отображении) а так сохранение происходит.

Comment: Смысл не в SurfaceView, а в том, что вы можете на любой канве нарисовать свои объекты.

Comment: Но мне нужно видеть мой surfaceView и сохранять, прошу помочь

Comment: Зачем вам видеть SurfaceView? Если для предварительного просмотра то опять таки рисуйте на Bitmap и выводите.

Comment: Мне нужен SurfaceView, т.к. я его использую для:
1. Динамического изображения(перемещения и добавления наложений)
2. Изменения самой картинки входящую в её расположение
Из за нового Bitmap'a не видно нового экрана, может подскажите как сделать Bitmap прозрачным?

Comment: Bitmap не надо выводить на экран. Прозрачным делают присваивая в альфа канал 0 (0x00ffffff для белого)

Comment: А как мне не выводить Bitmap если он через метод setBitmap выводится на Canvas.

Comment: так и Canvas можно создать в памяти и не выводить